# Compositor nodes are not affecting rendered video

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, video

I plan to use Blender exclusively as a video editor. I have put together a video in the sequencer and it renders without issues. However, I have also crated a node group to do some sharpening. It seems to be working fine in the viewer node, but is not reflected in the file output node, the sequence editor window or on the rendered video.

[image: compositor nodes]

Answer (score 5):

To bring the result of your nodes to the VSE you need to have an Output->Composite Node at the end of your node chain. On the VSE add a **scene** strip (Add Scene->Scene) and disable Open GL Preview.

[image]

NOTE:

If you just want to render the events in the compositor as a file to later rework on the VSE then you need to disable the sequencer temporarily. Then your file output nodes will work as expected.

[image]

Comment: If the answer works for you please mark it as accepted. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This answer belongs in the Blender Manual. Took me way to long to find.